# Difficulty on retrieving email address on a register form with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, member, email-validation

Hi im am trying to allow users to be members in a website. The code I have does not look to have any bugs or anything. When i try to register as a user it keeps show me an error that i haven't inserted the email address. The email field does exists in the database and i cannot find the problem.

PHP Script

```
$errorMsg = "";
// First we check to see if the form has been submitted 
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    //Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
    // Filter the posted variables
    $username = str_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['username']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $country = str_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['country']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $county = str_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['county']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $city = str_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['city']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $accounttype = str_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['accounttype']); // filter everything but lowercase letters
    $email=str_replace( '/@/', '&#64;', $email ); 
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = str_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Check to see if the user filled all fields with
    // the "Required"(*) symbol next to them in the join form
    // and print out to them what they have forgotten to put in
    if((!$username) || (!$country) || (!$county) || (!$city) || (!$accounttype) || (!$email) || (!$password)){

        $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
        if(!$username){
            $errorMsg .= "--- User Name";
        } else if(!$country){
            $errorMsg .= "--- Country"; 
        } else if(!$county){ 
            $errorMsg .= "--- State"; 
       } else if(!$city){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- City"; 
       } else if(!$accounttype){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Account Type"; 
       } else if(!$email){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
       } else if(!$password){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Password"; 
       }
    } else {
    // Database duplicate Fields Check
    $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    $username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
    if ($username_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    } else if ($email_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    } else {
        // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
       $hashedPass = md5($password); 
        // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, country, county, city, accounttype, email, password, signupdate) 
        VALUES('$username','$country','$state','$city','$accounttype','$email','$hashedPass', now())") or die (mysql_error());
        // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user files(pics, MP3s, etc.) 
        mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755); 
        // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
        $to = "$email";
        // Change this to your site admin email
        $from = "info@chrysikourtina.x10.mx";
        $subject = "Complete your registration";
        //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
        $message = '<html>
        <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Hi ' . $username . ',
        <br /><br />
        You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
        <br /><br />
        Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
        <a href="http://http://chrysikourtina.x10.mx/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
        ACTIVATE NOW</a>
        <br /><br />
        Your Login Data is as follows: 
        <br /><br />
        E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
        Password: ' . $password . ' 
        <br /><br /> 
        Thanks! 
        </body>
        </html>';
        // end of message
        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $to = "$to";
        // Finally send the activation email to the member
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        // Then print a message to the browser for the joiner 
        print "<br /><br /><br /><h4>OK $firstname, one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
        We just sent an Activation link to: $email<br /><br />
        <strong><font color=\"#990000\">Please check your email inbox in a moment</font></strong> to click on the Activation <br />
        Link inside the message. After email activation you can log in.";
        exit(); // Exit so the form and page does not display, just this success message
    } // Close else after database duplicate field value checks
  } // Close else after missing vars check
} //Close if $_POST
?>
```

HTML Form

```
 <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="7%">REGISTER AS A MEMBER HERE </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="5">
  <form action="join_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><font color="#FF0000"><?php echo "$errorMsg"; ?></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="163"><div align="right">User Name:</div></td>
      <td width="409"><input name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo "$username"; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Country:</div></td>
      <td><select name="country">
      <option value="<?php echo "$country"; ?>"><?php echo "$country"; ?></option>
      <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>

      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>

      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">County: </div></td>
      <td><input name="county" type="text" value="<?php echo "$county"; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">City: </div></td>
      <td>
        <input name="city" type="text" value="<?php echo "$city"; ?>" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Account Type: </div></td>
      <td><select name="accounttype">
        <option value="<?php echo "$accounttype"; ?>"><?php echo "$accounttype"; ?></option>
        <option value="a">Normal User</option>
        <option value="b">Expert User</option>
        <option value="c">Super User</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Email: </div></td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="<?php echo "$email"; ?>" value="<?php echo "$email"; ?>" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Password: </div></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>" /> 
      <font size="-2" color="#006600">(letters or numbers only, no spaces no symbols)</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Captcha: </div></td>
      <td>Add Captcha Here for security</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"></div></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Error : You did not submit the following required information!

--- Email Address

All the other fields seem to be working fine!! If anyone has any idea of what is causing the problem please tell me!! Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: I think you mixed up str_replace() with preg_replace(), are you using a kind of pattern there?

Comment: put your connect_to_db.php code , it can be something with mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Kindo correct way to build a question and close follow up the answers and comments. I give +1 for this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to first get post value, then play with it. So consider the order change as below:

```
$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$email=str_replace( '/@/', '&#64;', $email );     
$email = strip_tags($email);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
```

Also a check in html file may work for further errors.

```
<?php $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Nop :) doesn't work.. I've tried that previously!! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: can you help me by adding `print_r($email); die();` after first `$email` statement. If successfull, try next, till you find out where the error begins

Comment: it did work with these three functions:  $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
 $email = strip_tags($email);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

I don't know what was causing the comfussion..

Comment: final tip, then I'll give up. Set `$email = "";` before `$errorMsg = "";`. Let me know just to relief :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: IF you still get the same result the problem is with mysql_real_escape_string
because it's the only function which return FALSE.**

You forgot to define the value of the email variable.

add this:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

above this:

```
$email=str_replace( '/@/', '&#64;', $email );
```

and add this below:

```
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($email)));
```

Comment: I tried that.. It doesn't work though :/ Anyway with the code above i did define it with the str_replace function. It doesn't work either way

Comment: there's something with mysql_real_escape_string (updated my answer)

Comment: @Elena - No, you use the $email variable inside the str_replace function before grabbing it from the form. Then, in the next line, you grab the post data.

Comment: Update your question and include your connect_to_db.php code.

Comment: Nop :( that didn't work either.. Thanks for your advise it was helpful!! I will check the mysql_real_escape_string again and see if i get anything out :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` to display your variable's values. See what `$mail` is when it is posted but before any filters are applied, and after each filter is applied. This can narrow down your search to where the error is actually occurring.